# C++, VS2005 Please help me to resolve this compilation error

Tags: visual-c++

Code

```
   BOOL CGrAllObjects::ReorderObj(CGrObject* pGrFind,int ixObjNewIx)
   {

       int nSubCode,nLyrCode=pGrFind->GetLayerCode(nSubCode);
        CGrObject* pGrObject;
        CGrObjectArray* 
        pGrObjectArray=GetObjArrayFromCode(nLyrCode,nSubCode);

        if(!pGrObjectArray) return FALSE;

        for(int ixObj=pGrObjectArray->GetSize()-1; ixObj>=0; ixObj--)

        {       pGrObject=pGrObjectArray->GetAt(ixObj);

                if(pGrObject==pGrFind) break;

        }

        if(ixObj<0) return FALSE;

        if(ixObj!=ixObjNewIx)

        {       pGrObjectArray->RemoveAt(ixObj);

                pGrObjectArray->InsertAt(ixObjNewIx,pGrFind);
        }

        return TRUE;
}






Error: 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxx.cpp(359) : error C2065:
'ixObj' : undeclared identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int ixObj` ... the variable "ixObj" is only defined in the scope of the `for` loop and is not known outside.

Define the integer before the loop, and remove the decalration from 'for':

```
int ixObj;
for(ixObj=...
```